# Is it possible to use a Sony smartwatch as an airmouse by gyrometer?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, air, mouse, sony-smartwatch

I want to use a Sony smart watch to imitate an air mouse like Logitech MX Air. I am completely addicted to that mouse, and I have a really good feeling that having it attached to my wrist would be the most user friendly mouse ever.

The question is: Is it possible?

I can code anything in c#, I just want to do my proper research before I start, so I don't waste 20+ hours to find out it's not possible.

It should be a Bluetooth connection to the pc, using an app on the watch and an app/driver on the pc. The data flow must be very stable, that's probably the weak link in the project.

Can I get some feedback? Possible, not possible and why?

Comment: That would make watching p0rn quite complicated... Now more seriously, your question is too broad, please check the FAQs to see what and how ask in this site.

Comment: " I just want to do my proper research before I start" asking on here isn't how to research. You should research before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

The SmartWatch comes with an accelerometer giving you z y and z coordinate values. Check out this link to setup your development environment and try out the HelloSensors example.

https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smartwatch-2-apis/get-started/